ords 24.1 error/session crash when getting Hebrew chars as input
I am trying to use ords24.1 for plsql cartridge app. I can view data in Hebrew chars, but trying to input Hebrew characters, the HTTP session is broken with http 504 and I get this error on the console:
SEVERE      org.eclipse.jetty.http2.hpack.HpackException$SessionException: **Could not hpack encode HTTP/2.0{s=200,h=24,cl=-1}**
java.io.IOException: org.eclipse.jetty.http2.hpack.HpackException$SessionException: Could not hpack encode HTTP/2.0{s=200,h=24,cl=-1}
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.channelWrite(HttpOutput.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:858)
        at oracle.dbtools.http.servlet.NormalizedServletResponse$NormalizedOutputStream.write(NormalizedServletResponse.java:924)

I tried to change the encoding in pool.xml to ISO-8859-8 but still the odrs ignores it and uses UTF-8.
